# Watchos 2 Beta 5 Dynamic notification not showing,Only static notification interface loaded

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I have created apple watch application to show  push notificaiton.So I have created different dynamic notification interface with different category.but it's not showing dynamic interface but able to see action button for the respective category.Please help me.Please find the appdelegate push notification registration method

P.S: If run in simulator with payload it's working fine.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.




        // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
        if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {

         self.registerSettingsAndCategories()

        } else {
            // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }


        return true
    }

  func registerSettingsAndCategories() {



            let alarmAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            alarmAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Activate Theft Alarm ", comment: "Activate Theft Alarm ")
            alarmAction.identifier = "theftAlarm"
            alarmAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
            alarmAction.authenticationRequired = false

            let callCopsAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            callCopsAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Call Near by cops", comment: "Call Near by cops")
            callCopsAction.identifier = "callCops"
            callCopsAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
            callCopsAction.authenticationRequired = false

            let callSecAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            callSecAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Call Parking Security ", comment: "Call Parking Security ")
            callSecAction.identifier = "callSecurity"
            callSecAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
            callSecAction.authenticationRequired = false

            let navigateToSpotAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            navigateToSpotAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Navigate to Spot", comment: "Navigate to Spot")
            navigateToSpotAction.identifier = "navigateToSpot"
            navigateToSpotAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
            navigateToSpotAction.authenticationRequired = false


            let bookappointmentAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            bookappointmentAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Book Appointment", comment: "Book Appointment")
            bookappointmentAction.identifier = "bookAppointment"
            bookappointmentAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
            bookappointmentAction.authenticationRequired = false






            let theftCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            theftCategory.setActions([alarmAction, callCopsAction,callSecAction],
                forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
            theftCategory.setActions([callCopsAction,callSecAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
            theftCategory.identifier = "theftWarning"


            let accidentCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            accidentCategory.setActions([navigateToSpotAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
            accidentCategory.setActions([navigateToSpotAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
            accidentCategory.identifier = "accident"

            let lowOilCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            lowOilCategory.setActions([bookappointmentAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
            lowOilCategory.setActions([bookappointmentAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)
            lowOilCategory.identifier = "lowOil"


            let categories : Set<UIUserNotificationCategory> = [theftCategory, accidentCategory, lowOilCategory]

            // Configure other actions and categories and add them to the set...


            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletion: in your subclass of WKUserNotificationInterfaceController.

Then, execute completionHandler.

```
completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType.Custom)
```

WatchOS 2.0 document:

> The completion handler for telling the system what interface to
>   display. Execute this completion handler at the end of your method
>   implementation. If you do not execute this block in a timely manner,
>   the system displays your app’s static notification interface.

Comment: Hi  hiro_Kimu Thank you for reply  I have added completionHandler in WKUserNotificationInterfaceController

Comment: I unpaired and repaired apple watch now its working thanks